# how to increase length of selected section

Tags: mesh

In the picture attached how can I increase the length of the selected section (along its slightly tilted vertical axis I mean) so that everything else below moves down accordingly when I do so. Or, I cannot do it, and I must first separate what is below, increase length of what I want, and then rejoin what was separated from below?[image]